# Hidden View/ViewHolder in LinearLayout. Want to slide it down when it appears

Tags: android-animation, android

I have a View at the bottom of a LinearLayout, with visibility set to false.  I want it to slide down when it appears, and the slide animation is perfect, it's just that when it appears, it appears over all other content, when I Want it to appear as if it's coming in BEHIND the other objects (ie a lower zIndex). I tried to bringToFont() the other objects, as well as modifying the zAdjustment in the animation, but no luck.

This is my animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:zAdjustment="bottom" 
    >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:zAdjustment="bottom"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

and this my Java code:

```
View optionsView = findViewById(R.id.options_layout);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.anim.slide_top_down);
//findViewById(R.id.content_layout).bringToFront();
//this.invalidate();
optionsView.startAnimation(animation);
//this.addViewInLayout(optionsView,-1, optionsView.getLayoutParams());
if (optionsView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
    optionsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    optionsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Is there any way I can perform this slide down with it not appearing in front of all the objects as it comes down?